# Why can't get input value checkbox in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, checkbox, return-value

In the code described below, the value of the input should be taken from everyone in the array and a new div with the input value in innerHtml should be created. I don't know why get an error that length.value not defined?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxnewdivs" id="checkboxnewdivs" name="checkboxnewdivs" value="divsone">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxnewdivs" id="checkboxnewdivs" name="checkboxnewdivs" value="divstwo">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxnewdivs" id="checkboxnewdivs" name="checkboxnewdivs" value="divsthree">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

```
function myFunction() {
let array = [];
var checkboxnewdivs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkboxnewdivs"]:checked');

         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxnewdivs.length; i++) {
                     
         var iddivs = array.push(checkboxnewdivs[i].value);  
         
         var div_new = document.createElement("DIV"); 
         div_new.innerHTML = "ID div:"+iddivs ;                   
         document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div_new);
        
         }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var checkboxnewdivs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkboxnewdivs"]:checked').value;
```

Should be

```
var checkboxnewdivs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkboxnewdivs"]:checked');
```

The first one is trying to get a `value` property from a node collection, which will obviously be undefined.

You also had some typos (double 's') and don't define `array` anywhere. Define that where you defined `checkboxnewdivs`.

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mitya33/m9L2dvz5/1/

Comment: But then i get  ,  array.push(checkboxnewdivss[i].value) not defined?

Comment: Typo - `checkboxnewdivss` should be `checkboxnewdivs`

Comment: Actually you have several typos. Always check the error console.

Comment: Right, the next problem is you haven't defined `array` anywhere. This is plainly clear by the error that gets generated, `array is not defined` in the console. See edit.

Comment: How in yours exsample jsfiddle get value.., divone from input 1, divtwo from input 2, divthree from input 3 if is checked, and add in div_new innerHTML?